# SvelteKit routing for components

Tags: sveltekit

I have a left section containing a mini navbar (buttons: users, create, coins) and a right section containing the content I want to display (display coins section when coins button is clicked, ...)

However currently, the routing I want to achieve is not what I want at the moment.

When for example, the users button is clicked, I want the routing/url to be shown as `settings/users`, rather than just `settings`, `settings/create` for the create button and `settings/coins` for the coins button.

The following is the code:
**settings/+page.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores'
    import Create from './create/+page.svelte'
    import Users from './users/+page.svelte'
    import Coins from "./coins/+page.svelte"

    export let data
    let loading = false
    let currentSetting = 'create'
    $: currentSetting = $page.url.hash?.substring(1) || 'create';
</script>

<div class="flex mt-5 h-full">
    <!-- Left section -->
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center gap-4 w-44"> 
        <a href="#create" on:click={()=>{currentSetting='create'}} class="w-full btn btn-ghost         {currentSetting==='create' ? 'btn-active':''}">Create</a>
        <a href="#users" on:click={()=>{currentSetting='users'}} class="w-full btn btn-ghost {currentSetting==='users' ? 'btn-active':''}">Users</a>
        <a href="#coins" on:click={()=>{currentSetting='coins'}} class="w-full btn btn-ghost {currentSetting==='coins' ? 'btn-active':''}">Coins</a>
    </div>
    <div class="divider divider-horizontal"></div>

    <!-- Right section -->
    <div class="flex-1">
        {#if currentSetting==='create'}
            <Create categories={data?.categories}/>
        {:else if currentSetting==='users'}
            <Users bind:loading={loading} users={data.allUsers}/>
        {:else if currentSetting==='coins'}
            <Coins bind:loading={loading} users={data.allUsers}/>
        {/if}
    </div> 
</div>
```

where coins, create and users are all components in `settings/coins/+page.svelte`, `settings/create/+page.svelte` and `settings/users/+page.svelte` respectively.

When a button is clicked, `currentSetting` changes such that the display changes to the correct display (users button clicked, displays users settings.

I have tried using a pseudo route for each component, but I do not want to use it as it cannot have its own `+page.server.js`.

Thus, changing the link of a anchor tag is needed.

I was thinking of using slug, but I'm unsure of how to actually use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are confusing pages and components.

In SvelteKit, pages are placed under `/src/routes/` in a hierarchy that mirrors your desired URL paths to access each page. SvelteKit will then infer the routing from that `/src/routes/` directory structure. This is where you will define `+page.svelte`, `+page.js`, etc. files for page declarations, `+layout.svelte` etc. files for layouts, `+server.js` files for endpoints, etc.

You do not need to import pages in order to link to them, you simply use the standard HTML `<a href="...">...</a>` tag with the correct URL to reach the page you want linked to. For instance, a page declared as `/src/routes/settings/users/+page.svelte` will be, by convention, accessible on your site at `yoursite.com/settings/users` and can be linked to with `<a href="/settings/users">Users</a>`.

You can read about SvelteKit routing in detail [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).

In addition to pages, you can also create components, which are like reusable building blocks for your pages. These are typically placed under `/src/lib/` and have names like `MyForm.svelte`. These components *will* have to be imported in your page files before you can use them there.

You can find a typical SvelteKit project structure [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure).

**Complementary information: using layouts**

Layouts are part of the `/src/routes` tree and help define common structural elements shared by several pages.

Layouts usually apply to all the pages that are located below them in the `/src/routes/` directory hierarchy, although there are special mechanisms available to escape individual page files from using layout(s) that would normally apply to them.

Layouts can be *nested*. In your particular use case, for instance, you would want to locate your side navigation in `/src/routes/settings/+layout.svelte`. This is what it that file would look like:

```html
// /src/routes/settings/+layout.svelte

<script>
  export let data; // from the layout's load() function, see further below
  $: current = data.route.id
</script>

<div class="flex mt-5 h-full">
    <!-- Left section -->
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center gap-4 w-44"> 
        <a href="/settings/create" class="w-full btn btn-ghost {current === '/settings/create' ? 'btn-active':''}">Create</a>
        <a href="/settings/users" class="w-full btn btn-ghost {current === '/settings/users' ? 'btn-active':''}">Users</a>
        <a href="/settings/coins" class="w-full btn btn-ghost {current === '/settings/coins' ? 'btn-active':''}">Coins</a>
    </div>
    <div class="divider divider-horizontal"></div>

    <!-- Right section goes here -->
    <div class="flex-1">
      <slot></slot>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And the accompanying `/src/routes/settings/+layout.js`:

```js
// /src/routes/settings/+layout.js
export function load({ route }) {
  return { route };
}
```

The above `load` function will simply get the name of the route from the incoming request and pass it on to the layout (and its child pages). You need this in order to properly set the `btn-active` class in your side navigation for the currently active page.

With the layout defined above, any pages declared under `/src/routes/settings/` will apply this layout and be loaded into the `<slot></slot>` declared in the layout.

You can read more about SvelteKit layouts [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout).

Note that all of this is really the A-B-C of SvelteKit. I urge you to go back to the docs to get a solid grasp of a SvelteKit project structure and a thorough understanding of its routing/page structure conventions.

Comment: Yup I tried using `<a href="...">...</a>, but there is one problem. This replaces the whole page with the clicked content. I have a left and right section. When a button is clicked, such as coins, I just want the right section to change to the coins section, and not the whole page change. That's why, I believe `slot` is the way to do this as it doesn't change the whole page.

However, changing the URL when a button is clicked is another challenge for me.

Comment: [Layouts](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout) are the mechanism that will allow you to do that.

Comment: How do i do that? parent in layout and child as components? or are they in routes directory as well

Comment: See updated answer. You will want to go back to the basics to get a good understanding of how SvelteKit works.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. Clearly I still need to get a better grasp of sveltekit. I have also passed data into the component of users, coins and create, and also binding it to loading. How do I accomplish this with your code above?

Comment: I have tried

`{#if currentSetting === '/settings'}
    <slot categories={data?.categories}></slot>
{:else if currentSetting === '/settings/users'}
    <slot users={data.allUsers}></slot>
{:else if currentSetting === '/settings/coins'}
    <slot users={data.allUsers}></slot>
{/if}`


I have made the create file a +page, as that is the setting I want it to default to when the settings page is opened.

But it resulted in this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: Since `/settings/create/+page.svelte`, `/settings/users/+page.svelte` and `/settings/coins/+page.svelte` are *pages* and not *components*, you cannot pass data to them as you would with components. However each of these pages can have its own accompanying `+page.js` that will implement its own `load()` function that can  - among other things - fetch remote data to hydrate/populate the page. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-js and https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load

Comment: As for [`<slot>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-slot), they're merely markers/placeholders indicating where partial content should be loaded. Picture them as a parking spot, if you will, or a theater stage.